# hive: coalesce over a single column

Tags: hive

For my sample data below. I need to coalesce with the available productid over a given viewid. Is it possible using coalesce ?

```
date    viewid                         productid
5/1/17  100e9b59e70deb1493677845193    null
5/1/17  100e9b59e70deb1493677845193    12345
5/1/17  100e9b59e70deb1493677845193    null
```

Results:

```
date    viewid                         productid
5/1/17  100e9b59e70deb1493677845193    12345
5/1/17  100e9b59e70deb1493677845193    12345
5/1/17  100e9b59e70deb1493677845193    12345
```

Comment: Will a given viewid only have two possible productid values, null and the desired value?

Comment: No. viewid will always have the same product id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  `date`,viewid,min(productid) over (partition by viewid) as productid
from    mytable
```